# C pointer dereference

Tags: c

I wrote these instructions in a test program:

```
char *p;
```

then

```
p="gibberish";
```

went then to print p as follows

```
printf("%s\n", p);
```

and I got "gibberish" printed which surprised me as p address was not initialised; I was expecting an error when running the code but I have not...any explanation, please?

Also when using a struct with a pointer as one its fields, e.g.

```
struct dummy
{
int *m;
....
}
```

How can I dereference `m` in a dummy variable `dv`? I have tried `dv.m` and it did work although I was expecting `dv.(*m)`; any explanation please?

Comment: This should have been two questions, each of which would have been off topic, because any textbook on C answers them.

Comment: To access the pointer in the structure, you would use `*dv.m` or `dv.m[0]` or something similar; `dv.m` is simply the pointer. After a `.` or `->`, you always have a member name (a simple identifier, though it could be enclosed in parentheses if the coder was perverse enough and not kept under control by code reviewers).

Comment: "and I got "gibberish" printed which surprised me as p address was not initialised" - huh... what do you think `p = "gibberish";` does?

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, the line `p="gibberish"` initializes `p` to point at the first character of the string `"gibberish"`.

For the second question, assuming that `dv` is of type `struct dummy` and not of type `struct dummy *`, you want `*(dv.m)` to deference the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

This is also initialization:

```
int main()
{
    int t=3;
    int* p;
    p=&t; /* intitialization */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pointers are variables as well,

and "gibberish" is a literal string (study about it),
what you are doing right here

```
p="gibberish";
```

is taking the address of that literal string and assigning to **p** pointer

*the second question

pointers where made to point something

```
struct dummy dv;
int i =2;
dv.m=&i;
printf("%i",*dv.m);
```

first, you have to create something to point to, then assign it to the pointer

```
    dv.m=&i;
```

and then derreferencing the pointer
    printf("%i",*dv.m);